# SML Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm new to SML and don't quite understand my issue, although I'm certain I'm at fault. First off, here are two short functions I am testing and their descriptions.

**MakeInterval** - Takes a natural number *r*, (also used for *rp*) and a natural number *t*, and returns the interval [t-r,t+r].

```
fun MakeInterval(r,rp,t) =
    if r + rp < 0 then []
    else t-r :: MakeInterval(r-1,rp,t);
```

E.g. MakeInterval(3,3,10) will return [7,8,9,10,11,12,13]. If you have a suggestion for getting rid of *rp*, please let me know. It's the only way I could think of to keep track of the original value of *r* while maintaining sorted order.

**NotDivisible** - Takes a natural number *r*, a list of natural numbers *ts1* and another list of natural numbers *ts2*. Code using *ts2* isn't yet written.

*r* specifies the lower and upper bounds of the interval, (same as *MakeInterval*), and ts1 is a list of numbers to be fed into *map* with the MakeInterval function.

```
fun NotDivisible(r, ts1, ts2) = 
    map (fn x => MakeInterval(r,r,x), ts1);
```

This function should return a list of intervals. E.g. NotDivisible(3, [10,20,30],
 [2,4,6]) will return (for now) [[7..13], [17..23], [27..33]].

After I get this working, I will begin manipulating these lists to find which numbers out of these intervals are indivisible by any of the numbers in *ts2*.

But for now, my issue lies with the function definitions as I have them. *MakeInterval* is defined with no issues and I have tested it on it's own. This is the error I receive when attempting to define *NotDivisible*:

```
stdIn:5.33-5.71 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: 'Z -> 'Y
  operand:         (int -> int list) * 'X
  in expression:
    map ((fn x => MakeInterval <exp>),ts1)
```

I've tried specifying all types manually to no avail. Everything makes sense to me logically, but clearly there is a syntax issue here that I am not following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the above is the invocation of map, the function is curried

```
map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list;
```

so, a small change to the parentheses:

```
fun NotDivisible(r, ts1, ts2) = map (fn x => MakeInterval(r,r,x)) ts1;
```

gives you:

```
val NotDivisible = fn : int * int list * 'a -> int list list
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. Funny how such a small error can set me back hours.